# React Router: one way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd like to build a one-way route to a subpage with [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/). From that subpage I do not want to be able to go back.

```js
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h3>Im Home</h3>;
  }
}

export default class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/reports/home">Home</Link>
          <Route path="/reports/home" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Current behaviour**: I see the Link to "Home", even though I already clicked it.

**Wanted behaviour**: As soon as I click the Link to "Home", I don't want to see any navigation related components - only the pure Home Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move your components around.

Router at the top for your specified routes.

Then a route within there for navigation and another route for your reports/home.

```js
class Router extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
           <div>                  
               <Route path="/navigation" component={Navigation} />
               <Route path="/reports/home" component={Home} />
           </div>
       </Router>
    );
  }
}

class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div><Link to="/reports/home">Home</Link></div>;
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h3>Im Home</h3>;
  }
}
```

Comment: For your code I get the error message "Duplicate declaration 'Router'". If I rename "Router" to, let's say, "App", I do not see anything but a white window. No Home Link.

Comment: My fault, change the top Router component to a Navigationrouter or something like that and it should work